# BeanDefinitionOverrideException when supplying bean for integration test / @SpringBootTest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I configure a `Clock` bean like this:

```java
@Configuration
public class ClockConfiguration {

    @Bean
    Clock clock() {
        return Clock.systemDefaultZone();
    }
}
```

For an integration test, however, I need a `Clock` instance with a fixed time, so I added a static `@TestConfiguration` like this:

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = WireMockInitializer.class)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class MyIT {

    @TestConfiguration
    static class ClockTestConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public Clock clock() {
            return Clock.fixed(Instant.ofEpochMilli(1635513004000L), ZoneId.systemDefault());
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    WireMockServer wireMockServer;

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @AfterEach
    void afterEach() {
        wireMockServer.resetAll();
    }

    @Test
    void testFoo() {}
}
```

But when running the test, the application context cannot be loaded. Instead, this error message is shown:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'clock' defined in de.myapp.MyIT$ClockTestConfiguration

There is already [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=clockConfiguration; factoryMethodName=clock; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [de/myapp/ClockConfiguration.class]] bound.
```

My understanding was that the static `@TestConfiguration` would actually take care of that?

Comment: don't you also need `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Spring boot 2.0 and upwards, you have to enable bean overriding in application.yml to allow Spring to override the instance of `Clock` from the actual application with the one in you want in integration test:

```
spring:
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that several workarounds will be available.

1:
Set `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` on `src/test/resources/application.properties`(or on `application-test.properties`; you activate `test` profile) .

2:
If [`@Qualifier`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.12/reference/html/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) is not specified on auto-wiring, define test bean as [`@Primary`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.12/reference/html/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation-primary) with different [bean name](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.12/reference/html/core.html#beans-java-customizing-bean-naming):

```java
    @TestConfiguration
    static class ClockTestConfiguration {

        @Bean("fixedClock")
        @Primary
        public Clock clock() {
            return Clock.fixed(Instant.ofEpochMilli(1635513004000L), ZoneId.systemDefault());
        }
    }
```

See also:

- [Spring Boot 2.1.0 Erroneous BeanDefinitionOverrideException #15045](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15045#issuecomment-434775492)